# How to read stdin in zig

Tags: zig

I'm trying to read a file from stdin in zig but my approach seems a bit slow. So far I have:

```
var reader = std.io.getStdIn().reader();
var count: u32 = 0;
var buf: [1000]u8 = undefined;
while (try reader.readUntilDelimiterOrEof(&buf, '\n')) |line| {
    _ = line;
    count += 1;
}
```

Ive tried compiling with `zig build -Doptimize=ReleaseFast`, however reading a 10k line file using `less test.sam | time zig-test` takes around 1.2s, whilst using `less test.sam | time wc -l` takes 0.04s. Output of time command for zig-test was:
 `0.52s user 0.72s system 99% cpu 1.254 total`
Seems to be a lot of time spent in both system call and user.

Reading the file directly using this code reduced the time to a more reasonable 0.12s:

```
var file = try std.fs.cwd().openFile("test.sam", .{});
defer file.close();
var buf_reader = std.io.bufferedReader(file.reader());
var reader = buf_reader.reader();
var count: u32 = 0;
var buf: [10000]u8 = undefined;
while (try reader.readUntilDelimiterOrEof(&buf, '\n')) |line| {
    _ = line;
    count += 1;
}
```

Time output was:
`0.13s user 0.00s system 98% cpu 0.133 total`

Comment: Maybe antivirus is affecting the measurement? On my machine I get 0.064s from your Zig code and 0.023s from `wc -l`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but no antivirus switch on at the moment

Comment: Which Zig version are you using? Also, which OS?

Comment: Using mac BigSur and zig 0.11.0-dev.1908. I tried 0.11.0-dev.2777 but I havent been able to figure out some of the new api changes to build. Tried 0.10, but build api is also different to 0.11

Comment: I got it working on 0.10.1, but same issue '0.51s user 0.77s system 98% cpu 1.302 total'...

Answer (score 1):

You want to add buffering probably: https://zig.news/kristoff/how-to-add-buffering-to-a-writer-reader-in-zig-7jd

Comment: This looks more like a comment than an answer.